# Adobe Illustrator artboard color disappears, why?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

Somehow, I managed to turn off the background color of my artboards in Illustrator, so I can't see any differences between the background of the whole file and the artboards themselves.

Does someone know how to fix this problem? I want my artboards to have a white background again.

Comment: Did you switch on the transperncy grid?    Shift+CTRL+D toggles it. If you're on a mac use Command instead of CTRL.

Comment: No matter if I change this or not, my artboards are still having no background color oor border to let me see where it starts or ends...

Comment: What do you mean by "no background"?  Have you hidden the artboards? The toggle is Shift+CTRL+H

Comment: Did you enable overprint preview

Comment: I mean the Artboard itself does not have a background color as usual, it's like I would have no Artboards and the elements are just floating in the air. I just noticed that all my other AI files are fine, it's just one file that got this problem and I tryed really much but it does not seems to get better. I also tryed to turn on/off the overprint preview, that does not change anything except that some elements get darker.

Comment: View > Overprint Preview or View > Show Artboards

Comment: Try: Shift + Ctrl + H (view>>hide show/hide artboards.). Also: document setup>>simulate colored paper.

Comment: @LeoNas Thank you verry much! This was the solution! I dont know why I didn't think about this, was kinda obvious that it must be something like this when the artboards of just one file are not visible. Have a good one :-)

Comment: @LeoNas The only thing I dont get is why the background of the artboards isn't white anymore, I just have the borders back now.

Comment: Posting as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your artboard is hidden.

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (menu: view>>hide show/hide artboards).

Also: document setup > simulate colored paper and play with the colors in Transparency box. Then you can view that color when enabling the Transparency grid.

See the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit > Preferences > User Interface.
There you will find a slider to control the darkness of the area around your artboard:

[image]

Comment: Which version do you use? I use the latest CC version and under the path you mentioned I see a verry different interface. [link](http://prntscr.com/i5xgga)